# почему не сетится цвет на бэкграунде?

Tags: java

[![Подчеркнул нужное][1]][1]

почему не сетится цвет на бэкграунде? Вроде бы добавляю цвет на фрейм frame.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlxAR.png

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно вызвать контейнер.
Используйте этот код:

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
```

Comment: можете пяснить что такое getContentPane и почему я должен именно его использовать?

Comment: Метод вызывает содержимое фрейма. Многие операции с фреймом действуют именно посредством этого метода

Comment: то есть если я правильно понял, добавлять например кнопки или текстовые поля без этого метода прямиком на фрейм можно, а вот с другими операциями, чтобы они работали нужно использовать getContentPane()?

Comment: Во фрейм желательно добавить JPanel и уже внутри неё располагать необходимые компоненты. Меня как минимум учили так делать :)